# Display UITableViewController datasource in alternate cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController. I need to display a table cell followed by a cell that has an embedded UITextField. Basically i need to display the tableView datasource alternatively. Please help me on this.. Thanks.

EDIT #1: Imagine `NSMutableArray *tableData;` is the datasource for the table which has the following elements:

- `@"Apple"`
- `@"Mango"`
- `@"Watermelon"`

I want the UITableView to be displayed as:

- 1st cell: Apple
- 2nd cell: *text field to enter quantity*
- 3rd cell: Mango
- 4th cell: *text field to enter quantity*
- 5th cell: Watermelon
- 6th cell: *text field to enter quantity*
- 7th cell: *save button*

Comment: tell how u want to display the tableView datasource alternatively?

Comment: I have edited the question to show how the data has to be displayed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataSource method like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  return ([m_tableData count]*2)+1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.row == [m_tableData count]*2)
   {
      //cell with button
   }
   else
   {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row%2 == 0)
    {
      //cell with label for displaying values
    }
    else
    {
      //Load a cell that has an embedded UITextField
    }
   }
}
```